# Create non-reusable cells UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've seen tutorials where they create cells that follow a specific pattern (each have a label that displays text from an array etc.) but I want to create cells that are different from each other. I was thinking of adding them like how you'd add an image with code (create constant, set position and then `view.addSubView(image))` but that isn't working.

I'm using swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an unique reuse identifier for every cell. That would technically disable the reuse mechanism. So if the cells content is unique but the size the same this should work, although I think it is a better way to reuse the cells and reset the content area.
If the cell size is different you must find a suitable layout at first.

Comment: The thing is that visually all the cells are basically the same, just an image button. But I want to set a variable to a different string value when each is pressed and this is my best guess on how to do it @oliverM

Comment: @NolanRanolin since the cells are visually basically the same, you can still use reusable cells with custom cells.  Base on the different `indexPath` display different contents.

Comment: Would you have any sample code (newbie and haven't done much with collectionview)

Comment: you can create a custom collectionviewcell and hold the value as property and read this value on didSelectCell() or set the string at this point